# $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has a unique subgroup of order $2$ then it is cyclic for $n >2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

If $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has a unique subgroup of order $2$  then it is cyclic, where $n>2$. That is, we have to show $n= 4, p^k,2p^k, p $ is odd prime.

I don't know if it is correct statement or not. But I suppose it is correct. If it is true please provide some hints to prove, otherwise please give some counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Hint:$ If an abelian group $G$ can be written as $A \times B \times C$, with $A$ and $B$ of even order, then $G$ has at least two elements of order $2$.

Apply this to the decomposition
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times\cong (\mathbb{Z}/{p_1^{k_1}}\mathbb{Z})^\times \times (\mathbb{Z}/{p_2^{k_2}}\mathbb{Z})^\times  \times (\mathbb{Z}/{p_3^{k_3}}\mathbb{Z})^\times \times \cdots
$$
given by the Chinese remainder theorem when $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}p_3^{k_3}\cdots$.

Comment: As then by Cauchy's theorem there exists $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $(a,0,0) $ & $(0,b,0)$ are two elements of order two of $G$ which leads a contradiction. Am I right?

Comment: @analysis89, yes.